# Javascript order of operations upon clicking a link - link launched or listener attached to id fired

Tags: javascript, dom

When the following link is clicked, is the URL launched before a javascript listening to triggerclick is fired?

`<a id="triggerclick" target="_blank" href="http://domain.com">Click</a>`

Is there a way to get triggerclick to fire before the link is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a registered listener for the link then it'll fire and in your listener, you can prevent the link's default behavior by using

```
function myListener(e){

    // all code goes here

    // this code will stop the link to navigate
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    else e.returnValue = false;
}
```

You can also use `return false` like

```
function myListener(e){
    // all code goes here
    return false;
}
```

If you use none of those mentioned above then the link will navigate away but code inside the listener will be executed. So, yes, at first the `JavaScript` listener (if have any) fires and from there you can control the default behavior. Check this for [event registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).